# Ionic 3 set value in html template

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, angular-ngmodel

I am trying to set a value in an Ionic 3 template from my ts file, however I am also appending css to it at the same time. I am getting this error

#### ERROR

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'image'
>   Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'image'

My code is a s follows.

#### HTML

```
<img name="image" [(ngModel)]="image" id="image" src="https://openclipart.org/image/2400px/svg_to_png/247149/dual-compass-rose.png" alt="">
```

#### TS

```
this.image.style.transform = 'rotate(' + this.magneticHeading + 'deg)';
```

I am not sure why this is not working but am starting to think that angular doesn't like what I'm trying to do in the TS file by `.style.transform...`

Comment: Is there a reason to set ngmodel and src at the same time?

Comment: no reason but would this affect anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use @ViewChild to reference image tag from your DOM. Use [src] and not ngModel:

**Typescript:**

```
  @ViewChild('myImage') myImage;
  magneticHeading = '100';
  image="https://openclipart.org/image/2400px/svg_to_png/247149/dual-compass-rose.png"
  ...
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.myImage.nativeElement.style.transform = 'rotate(' + this.magneticHeading + 'deg)';
  }
```

**HTML:**

```
  <img #myImage name="image" id="image" [src]="image" alt="">
```

[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-whca4y)

Or to set it from HTML:

```
  <img #myImage [style.transform]="'rotate(' + magneticHeading + 'deg)'" name="image" id="image" [src]="image" alt="">
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-ezusmn)**

Comment: aha, this works, thanks a lot @vega, marked as correct answer

Comment: Your update works even better, image seems to rotate a lot more smoother. Really appreciate your time Vega, many thanks

Comment: I am glad was able to help :)